# UIImagePNGRepresentation increasing output file size instead of reducing the size

Tags: iphone, ios, png, jpeg

If we convert a JPEG file using UIImagePNGRepresentation, then the new file size is more. 
If we convert a PNG file using UIImagePNGRepresentation, then the new file size is less.

Why converting JPEG to PNG is costlier here?

Thanks Jithen

Comment: You are loading a png and then saving it as a png. Is this what you intend? What difference in file size do you see?

Comment: Yes. Loading a png and saving it as a new png. But new png file size is more than original png file. Original one is 155 kb and new file is around 266 kb..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411369/when-i-am-using-uiimagepngrepresentation-or-uiimagejpegrepresentation-for-conver

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the image size u can use following code

```
CGFloat compression = 222.0f;
CGFloat maxCompression = 202.1f;
int maxFileSize = 160*165; //fill your size need

NSData *imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image, compression);

while ([imageDat length] > maxFileSize && compression > maxCompression)
{
compression -= 0.1222;
imageDat = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(decodedimage.image, compression);
}
NSLog(@"image compressed success");

[image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageDat]];//image is my UIImageview
```

Hop this Helps !!!

Comment: Yeah following the same procedure.. but as an alternate method, i can convert all the images to PNG format, as PNG is in general less sized images.. So i would like to know why after converting the size is becoming more..

Comment: @Vishnu Your method is returning a compressed JPG ... the asker wants a compressed PNG.

Comment: @jithen A solution I've thought of is using PHP to create a PNG (as PHP allows for PNG compression (0-9) and using a UIWebView to execute the php in your iOS app!