# UIImage actual size size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am getting UIImage from `UIImagePickerController`:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage * originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((originalImage), 1.0)];
    NSUInteger length = imageData.length;
    [[self fileSizeLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File Size : %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:imageData.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]]];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is the length is bigger than the actual image size.for example the real image size is 1.2 MB and in this function i get 9.0MB.

Why the image size is not the same as the real image?

Comment: are u saying that originalImage.size is 9MB ? and the same image in device is 1.2 MB ?

Comment: You just count the length of the NSData like this.
[[self fileSizeLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File Size : %d",[imageData length]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [When i am using UIImagePNGRepresentation or UIImageJPEGRepresentation for converting UIImage into NSdata, the image size is too much increased](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411369/when-i-am-using-uiimagepngrepresentation-or-uiimagejpegrepresentation-for-conver).

Apparently, the original image may already be compressed - what type of file is it? `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` uncompresses the image and recompresses it to a JPEG representation.  If the original image was compressed to a lower quality than if maximum quality of the JPEG representation, then the new format will be a larger size.