# Can't figure out file size on iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, image

I've been checking different solutions that I've found through StackOverflow but sadly I couldn't find the solution to this problem. I basically need to find the size (in bytes, Kb or whatever) to an image that is stored in the iPhone Image gallery. Actually, I need to validate the size before uploading it to a server.

So, I took a JPEG  image from the internet:

http://static1.uk.businessinsider.com/image/596c82d34af3fa51058b4978-707/david%20slater.jpeg

Once I download this to my computer, when i get the file information it says:
Size 80865 bytes (82 KB on disk). So, I save this file to the iPhone's image library. Once I get the image from the gallery and I inspect it through xCode I see the following:

[image: xcode picture and info from file]

So, basically the file has 80865 bytes when it's on my computers disk, but it has 289371 when I inspect it through xcode (the method length from the NSData object returns 'the number of bytes contained by the data object' according to the documentation). Am I missing something? Why is the image inside the iPhone disk almost 4 times the size of the image stored in the iPhone?

The code I am using is:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSUInteger  length = [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0f) length];
}
```

**EDIT:** Ok, so I've changed the code to save the image to disk first and check the size then, I use:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage     *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSArray     *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString    *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image,1.0f) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    NSError     *attributesError;
    NSDictionary*fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&attributesError];
    NSNumber    *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
}
```

So, If i print the value of the variable fileSizeNumber I get: 369055 (which according to the documentation indicated the file's size in bytes). But this number doesn't seem to match the original 80865 either, it is actually 10 times bigger than the original image!

Comment: Please post code as text in your question, not as an image.

Comment: The size you are printing has absolutely nothing to do with the file size on disk. They are not related at all.

Comment: There isn't much code I'm using basically, buy I've added it. Tjanks @rmaddy

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411369/when-i-am-using-uiimagepngrepresentation-or-uiimagejpegrepresentation-for-conver

Comment: The in-memory size can and will be different than the size on disk.  Save it to disk first, then get the file size.

Comment: @i_am_jorf But the code is printing what the disk size will be if that JPG data is saved. The issue is that it has nothing to do with the originally downloaded image size that was added to the photo library.

Comment: @rmaddy I've changed the code and saved it to the disk but it still doesn't seem to match.

Comment: Did you review the link I posted? There is no reason at all the two size should be the same.

Comment: Yes, I reviewed the link, thanks. So, I changed the code basically. I can't understund why I save a jpeg image, I recreate the JPEG and save it they should match or be at least close. Why do they differ so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];`

You're writing the uncompressed data (or at least differently compressed data) to a file and then checking its length. But the point the JPEG file format is that it compresses the data. It's not surprising that reading a JPEG image, writing it to a file as PNG data, and then looking at the length of that file doesn't tell you what you want.

I'm not sure why you don't believe what Xcode is telling you, but if you feel driven to see the actual size of the JPEG image in its compressed state, you'll need to find the JPEG file itself. You'd do something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"selfie" ofType:@"jpeg"];
```

to get a path to the file, and then use `NSFileManager` to look at the attributes of the file at that path.

Comment: The problem is that the image is not really on the iPhone's "disk" but on the image gallery. I couldn't find a feasible way to get the actual URL of the actual file on the disk, and it actually seems to make sense in the context of iOS restrictions.

Comment: I've update my question's code from PNG to JPEG, to keep asking despite this. Still doesn't seem to match.